# Check a checkbox if a column contain an specific text on Google sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-statements

I hope someone can help me with this.

I want to achieve the following condition:
When column B contains "10:00 PM" set columns "M" and "N" as true (checkbox).

I tried this code:

```
   function sutenn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Status')
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();//this was they key this returns a string not a date
  let o =vs.map((r, i) => {
    if ((r[1] == "10:00 PM" && (r[6] == "")) || ((r[2] == "Sunday") || (r[3] == "Sunday" ))) {
      r[12] = true;
    } else {
      r[12] = false
    }
    return [r[12]];
  });
  
  sh.getRange(2,13,o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);//setting the checkboxes
}
```

But it didn't work.
Does someone know what should I do to achieve this condition?

Comment: You need to use `getValues()` and loop over. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function sutenn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn());
  const vs = rg.getDisplayValues();//this was they key this returns a string not a date
  let o =vs.map((r, i) => {
    if (r[1] == "10:00 PM") {
      r[12] = true;
    } else {
      r[12] = false
    }
    return [r[12]];
  });
  sh.getRange(2,13,o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);//setting the checkboxes
}
```

I just generated some test data and added some checkboxes
and this is what it looked like after running

[image]

I rewrote it in a different way so that you can hopefully achieve the additional conditions that you have not articulated very well on you own.

```
function ltesto() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  let o = vs.map((r, i) => {
    let [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N] = r;
    if (B == "10:00 PM") {
      M = true;
    } else if (G == '' && C == "Sunday" && D == "Sunday") {
      M = true;
    } else {
      M = false;
    }
    return [M];
  });
  sh.getRange(2, 13, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

If you wish to add addtional logical conditions the please suppy me with a truth table.

Comment: Thank you so much! it seems it works. I tried to add some extra conditions and they work as well but I had a problem trying to set a condition in which a cell is blank. Could you help me again? 

The conditions would be the following: 

If column B contains "10:00 PM" OR (column C = 'Sunday' OR column D = 'Sunday') set column "M" as true (checkbox). but do this condition just if column G is empty.

 I've edited my question so you can check how I modified the code. Sorry for still bothering you with this again but I hope you can help me again. Thank you!

Comment: As I said in my answer your conditions are not explain well enough for me.  I would suggest that you ask another question and supply us with a truth table so that we know exactly what you want.

Comment: Oh sorry! I didn't notice you asked me for a truth table. Sure! I will do a new question and I'll include it. Thanks for the help, Cooper!